# Since when did the Community user edit posts?

Tags: support, edits, community-user

Now I have truly seen everything. The community user does a lot of things, but editing answers to add information? Now **that** is truly bizarre.

What am I talking about? Have a look at the revisions to [this](https://askubuntu.com/posts/28773/revisions) question. Yeah, that's right - the community user suggested an edit that adds to the answer.

What is going on? Do we need to fear the new intelligent bots? Should we run for cover... or should we try to get rid of it?

<sub>A plausible explanation of what happened here would be great if nobody can think of a good defense strategy.</sub>

Comment: +1 for the cheesy title, as well as because THIS IS NUTS.

Comment: Community user became self-aware on August 4th, 1997, and Judgment Day ensued on August 29th.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is just an [anonymous edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/6835):

[image]

Comment: Really... it's that simple? :)

Comment: @George yes it is :)

Comment: Aw... so much for the conspiracy theories. Thanks for being so quick to point this out.

Comment: Its too bad that that this doesn't work on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @George: I'm disappointed in you. [A good conspiracy theorist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83748/eeeek-how-does-this-question-have-28-and-growing-close-votes-without-being-cl/83758#83758) doesn't let little things like "facts" get in the way.