# Did Community ♦ edit this answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, community-user

[I was looking at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156526/1085891) when I noticed that [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) made the last edit. [See revision here.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1156526/revisions)

[image: Revision made by Community?]

Am I reading this incorrectly? Was this an approval of an edit?

Comment: Probably a suggested edit by an anonymous user, approved by the community.

Comment: Yep: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/400998

Comment: I had the impression accepted suggestions from anonymous users were always adopted by Community.

Comment: @DanielFischer, that may be true. Ignorance on my part.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104318/since-when-did-the-community-user-become-sentient?lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anonymous users can suggest edits on posts. When these are accepted, Community adopts them.

It is all heart, like that.

See the revision for that specific edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/400998